# Interpreting numeric output for a categorical dependent

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data

I have a dataset where I want to predict a category from independent variables. The category output can take a number of values, not just a boolean choice.

```
> cars  <- data.frame(Speed  = c(  47,     49,      32,      27,        12,      11),
                      Colour = c("Red", "Red", "Other", "Other",  "Purple", "Purple"))
> cars$Colour <- as.factor(cars$Colour)

> model <- glm(Colour ~ Speed, family=binomial, data=cars)
> predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Speed = c(48)))
        1 
0.7136062
```

How do I interpret 0.7136062 in the context of the Colour choices I have?

**Edit: so how do I get the probability that the test where Speed=48 is Red, Purple, Other?**

Obviously I could change Colours to be dummy variables: is_red, is_purple but this example is contrived - there may be many more Colours or whatever.

Comment: Do you understand what the word 'binomial' means?

Comment: For `glm` with logistic regression, `predict` by default returns the log(odds) of the outcome, . For example, if your reference category is "Red", then `predict` returns the log(odds) of Not Red. If you want the *probability* of Not Red, add `type="response"` to your call to `predict`. See the help for `predict.glm` for more info.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you. I think I understand the difference between type=link/response now but how do I use `predict.glm` to get the likelihood probability of Not Purple then or Not Other? What indicates that this is the probability for Not Red?

Comment: from `?binomial`: `[when the dependent variable is] a factor: ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and hence usually of having the second level).`   If you want >2 categories in your response you may need to look at a multinomial model.

Comment: For a binomial model (logistic regression using `glm`), `glm` will (silently) collapse all the categories to reference category or not reference category. In your case, since you didn't specify an ordering of the factor levels, `as.factor` will order them alphabetically, meaning "Other" is the reference category in your model. To set the levels in a given order, you can specify them explicity, for example, `factor(cars$Colour, levels=c("Red", "Purple", "Other")`, will make "Red" the reference level.

Comment: But, as @BenBolker pointed out, a multinomial model is more appropriate if you want predictions for all the category levels.

Comment: @eipi10 I see now - and BondedDust's comment now makes more sense - a conceptual misunderstanding rather than syntax. I'll look in to multinomial models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, a multinomial model will give predictions that tell you which category is the most likely.

```
library(nnet)

cars  <- data.frame(Speed  = c(  47,     49,      32,      27,        12,      11),
                    Colour = c("Red", "Red", "Other", "Other",  "Purple", "Purple"))
cars$Colour <- as.factor(cars$Colour)

model <- multinom(Colour ~ Speed, family=binomial, data=cars)    
summary(model)
predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Speed = c(48)))
```